# How to model top part of the camera?

Tags: modeling

Learning subdiv modeling and stucked at this (marked with red curve). How would you model top part of the camera.

[image]

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  More info could be helpful, such as a wireframe/editmode screenshot of your model (the red indicator line seems to be obscuring the issue you want help with).  Also, the Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files, it's often a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to guess the design with only one view, but maybe try something like that:

[image]

Begin with the profile, then extrude:

[image]

[image]

Add loop cuts, extrude inwards:

[image]

[image]

Add loop cuts, move them to round the shape :

[image]

At a certain point, use a Mirror modifier, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how did you do this? What's the strategy of modeling this kinda things? It's more like manual tweaking polygons or what?

Comment: I've edited to add some steps

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the way.